# Character entity converted to chr

Tags: xml, coldfusion, coldfusion-2016

I have an XML file, sometimes I need to duplicate that XML by reading and replacing a few of it's nodes with different values. But after replacing the nodes, other unrelated nodes convert entities back to chars. For example:

```
<cfsavecontent variable="wsXML">
  <data>
    <jobnumber>101</jobnumber>
    <jobdesc>test desc</jobdesc>
        <question>
          <id>323</id>
          <order>0</order>
          <optional>false</optional>
          <text>Were there multiple entities or named insured&apos;s?</text>
          <type>MC</type>
          <section>REM</section>
          <basis>*</basis>
          <audit>*</audit>
          <min>0</min>
          <max>0</max>
          <options>
            <string>There were no multiple entities.</string>
            <string>There were multiple entities, shown &amp; described separately.</string>
          </options>
          <answer>There were no multiple entities.</answer>
        </question>
        <question>
          <id>324</id>
          <order>1</order>
          <optional>false</optional>
          <text>Were there multiple locations?</text>
          <type>YESNO</type>
          <section>REM</section>
          <basis>*</basis>
          <audit>*</audit>
          <min>0</min>
          <max>0</max>
          <options/>
          <answer>No</answer>
        </question>
    </data>    
</cfsavecontent>
<cfset DestPath = "C:\ColdFusion2016\cfusion\wwwroot\TestFiles">
<cfset JobData = XmlParse(wsXML)>
        <!---assign the new auditid--->
        <cfset JobData.data.jobNumber.xmlText = 100021>
        <cfset JobData.data.jobdesc.xmlText = "">
<cffile action="write" file="#DestPath#/New100021.xml" output="#JobData#" charset="utf-8">
```

When I read New100021.xml I see `&apos;` converted to `'` (apostrophe) and `&amp;` is converted to `&` (ampersand). How I can prevent losing the entities?

Note: data which I put up in `cfsavecontent` actually comes from database and I do not have any control over that.

Comment: Have you tried using the `xmlFormat()` function? Something like `<cffile action="write" file="#DestPath#/New100021.xml" output="#xmlFormat(JobData)#" charset="utf-8">`.

Comment: @Miguel-F, yes I tried that. But that convert even the xml nodes too.

Comment: Oh right, that makes sense.  Sorry.

Comment: @CFML_Developer, I've checked your code in my local by using CF2016. I can't reproduce your issue for &. But I can reproduce for ' (apostrophe). Please check the screen shot below. This screen shot is an output of New100021.xml file. 
https://gyazo.com/3c1abc3948f96c823e55083269e9fb80
 Will update you if once get the solution for that.

Answer (score 1):

If you rely on ColdFusion's `xmlParse`, you might be out of luck here. See this example:

```
<cfsavecontent variable="x">
    <node doubleQuote="&lt;, &amp;, &#x26;, &gt;, &quot;, &apos;" singleQuote='&lt;, &amp;, &#x26;, &gt;, &quot;, &apos;'>
        &lt;, &amp;, &#x26;, &gt;, &quot;, &apos;
    </node>
</cfsavecontent>

<cfset fileWrite(
    expandPath("test.xml"),
    xmlParse(x)
)>
```

The output is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<node doubleQuote="&lt;, &amp;, >, &quot;, '" singleQuote="&lt;, &amp;, >, &quot;, '">
    &lt;, &amp;, &amp;, &gt;, ", '
</node>
```

As you can see, the parser generates the XML completely anew, according to its "own" rules. All attributes are wrapped in double quotes, so there's no more need to encode apostrophe in attribute values, but just the double quote. In the node body (`.XmlText`), there is no need to encode apostrophe and double quote at all, so it's not done. Also, the previous entities are (re)encoded using HTML named entities. Technically this is valid XML, that is somewhat "HTML4 friendly" at the same time (`&apos;` is an unknown entity in HTML4).

You will need to rebuild the whole XML document as string by yourself or use a different Java library to build the XML.